# Why am I getting SSLError: <unprintable SSLError object> when using requests in python

Tags: openssl, python-requests, web2py

I was using requests without any issues until now but today I am getting this error and don't know why. I guess it have something to do with a certificate I created for web2py using this guide: http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/140

Could the fact that I generated a certificate mess with the way requests work and gives me this error? How can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Really need more info to help with this. Something is probably wrong with your certificates. What do you mean by no issues until today, did you have a certificate before? Are you running on your own server or somewhere like pythonanywhere?

Comment: I was using the requests library without issues until now, I wasn't aware about certificates until this error, I am running this on a digitalocean instance, about the code I was just making a get with requests.

Comment: OK, I didn't realise you meant you were using the Python Requests lib. Still not clear on your set up. Do you mean you have web2py on digital ocean, which exposes an API, which you are calling using "requests" from somewhere else...?

Comment: Actually I have 2 applications, a web2py site for which I wanted to have access to the error tickets (available only through https) and for which I followed the steps provided by the link I posted and another python script which I use to consume several rest services, some of them are still working fine but one of them started to give me this SSLError when I try to get the endpoint using the requests library so I am using requests for my script but no for my web2py app, nevertheless my problem start after I generated my certificates for my web2py app

Comment: Can you try making those calls using a different tool (maybe www.hurl.it or http://requestb.in/) to see what they say?

Comment: In my case, this error came about because the time on the machine was wrong.